# How do you trigger ngClass change on click in an angular component with jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, components, karma-runner

The click doesn't seem to be triggered and isn't changing the ngClass to active on the button I'm trying to click.

--

HTML:

```
<div class='btn-group' role='group' aria-label="">
    <button type='button'
    id='btn-group-btn-{{i}}'
    *ngFor="let button of buttons; index as i"
    (click)="onClick($event, i)"
    [ngClass]="{'active': button.isActive}"
    class='btn btn-default btn-primary'>
        {{button.displayTxt}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Component:

```
export class AdmitOneBtnGroup {
    @Input() public btnDisplayText: string;
    @Input() public id: string;
    @Output() public clickEvent = new EventEmitter();
    @Input() public buttons: Array<ButtonGroupButton>; // Should be array of objects

    public onClick($event, btnIndx) {
        this.buttons.forEach((button, currentIndx) => {
            button.isActive = (currentIndx === btnIndx);
        });

        this.clickEvent.emit(btnIndx);
    }
};

export interface ButtonGroupButton {
    isActive: boolean,
    displayTxt: string,
}
```

Test:

```
    let component: AdmitOneBtnGroup;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdmitOneBtnGroup>;
    const testData: Array<ButtonGroupButton> = [
        {
            displayTxt: "abc",
            isActive: true,
        },
        {
            displayTxt: "def",
            isActive: false,
        },
        {
            displayTxt: "ghi",
            isActive: false,
        },
    ]

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AdmitOneBtnGroup],
        }).compileComponents()
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdmitOneBtnGroup);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.buttons = testData;
        component.id = 'button-group'
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });


    it('#AdmitOneBtnGroupComponent button click should activate new button', async(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'onClick');

        const btn: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#btn-group-btn-1')
        const clickEvent = new Event('click');
        btn.dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(btn.getAttribute('class')).toContain("active");
        })
    }));
```

The test should be clicking the second button and adding the active class to it, but the active class is remaining on the first button..

I have an event above that says expect(component.onClick).toHaveBeenCalled(); comes out true so I'm not sure if the click isnt being triggered or if its just the ngClass that isn't being changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're spying on the function that sets the button's property of isActive to true here:

```
spyOn(component, 'onClick');
```

When you spy on a function, it isn't called unless you add .and.callThrough() to the end of the spyOn function.  If you remove the spy, I would expect it to work.

Alternatively, it could be:

```
spyOn(component, 'onClick').and.callThrough();
```

...but I'm not sure why you're spying on the function in the first place.